# In Soap UI, run multiple test suites dynamically in serial order

Tags: groovy, soapui

In Soap UI, i have more than 1 test suites in project.xml file i need to click on each test suites to run. is there any method through which i can invoke test suites dynamically in serial order?

Answer (score 1):

On `navigator` window double click on the project which contains the testSuites, select the testSuite tab on the new open panel, select run in sequence option an click on play.

[image]

Hope this helps,